# Background compilation with notifications

Tags: compiling

I've started running `while : ; do latexmk -lualatex main; sleep 1; done` in the background to have my document recompiled whenever one of its files is saved.  That works fine, but it would be nice to get notified on two occations: when a compilation is completed; and when there is an error that halts a compilation.  On a Mac, the first could be an `osascript -e 'beep'` and the second a `say compilation error`.  Any idea how that might be done?

Comment: Why the loop have you looked at the -pvc option?

Comment: @daleif, nice, I didn't know about that.

Comment: I think you'd end up being annoyed if it should beep every time it was finished compiling. I do two configurations: enable synctex and let latex stop on the first error. Just works.

Comment: @daleif, I'm using a visual bell, which isn't so annoying.  what do you mean you let latex stop on the first error? what annoys me a bit is that, if an error occurs, I won't know about it untill I check.

Answer (score 1):

A bit too long for a comment. First of, I have this in my `.latexmkrc`

```perl
$pdflatex = "pdflatex -synctex=1  -halt-on-error %O %S";
```

meaning that compilation will stop on the first error, and the go back and wait for me save changes.

I generally use an editor that covers 90% of the height of my screen, behind it I run `latexmk -pdf -pvc ...` at max size, that way I can usually visually see if the compilation went bad.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I put `$pdflatex = 'lualatex -halt-on-error %O %S; (( $? )) && say erreur'`

Comment: @Lawrence That might break latexmk , I do not remember if latexmk looks at the exit code of the latex process

Comment: it works well so far. even added an else clause